# how to extract a particular id from the string using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I want to extract a particular ids from the records in a table.For example i have a below table

```
Id   stringvalue
1    test (ID 123) where another ID 2596
2    next ID145 and the condition I(ID 635,897,900)
```

I want the result set as below

```
ID SV
1  123,2596
2  145,635,897,900
```

i have tried the below query which extracts only one ID from the string:

`Select Left(substring(string,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',string),Len(string)),3) from Table1`

Comment: This is gonna be a pain in sql server. Better do in some programming language using regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously don't encourage the T-SQL approach (as SQL is not meant to do this), however, a working version is presented below  -

Try this

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,StringValue VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO @T 
    SELECT 'test (ID 123) where another ID 2596' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'next ID145 and the condition I(ID 635,897,900)'

;WITH SplitCTE AS(
SELECT 
    F1.ID, 
    X.SplitData 
    ,Position = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', X.SplitData)
FROM (
    SELECT *,   
    CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(StringValue,' ',','),',','</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS XmlFilter 
    FROM @T F
    )F1
    CROSS APPLY
    ( 
    SELECT fdata.D.value('.','varchar(50)') AS SplitData 
    FROM f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') AS fdata(D)) X
    WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', X.SplitData) > 0),
    numericCTE AS(
    SELECT 
        ID
        ,AllNumeric = LEFT(SUBSTRING(SplitData, Position, LEN(SplitData)), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(SplitData, Position, LEN(SplitData)) + 't') - 1)      
    FROM SplitCTE  
)

SELECT
    ID
    ,STUFF(( SELECT ',' + c1.AllNumeric
                FROM numericCTE c1
                WHERE c1.ID = c2.ID
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS SV
FROM numericCTE c2
GROUP BY ID
```

/*
Result

```
ID  SV
1   123,2596
2   145,635,897,900
```

*/

However, I completely agree with @Giorgi Nakeuri. It is better to use some programming language (if you have that at your disposal) and use regular expression for the same. You can figure out that, I have used REPLACE function two times, first to replace the blank space and second to replace the commas(,).
Hope you will get some idea to move on.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but you are just encourage really bad practises. +1 if you remove the SQL, and leave the comment at the end :-)